# Redirect to URL upon drop down menu selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I'm true newbie so please bear with my stupid question.
I have a multi-stage questionnaire and I want to exempt users from pushing a "next" button every time they make a selection. 
Can someone please share with me a script that redirects users to a URL upon selection (regardless of the actual selection they have made)?

Thanks!

Comment: we all are here to learn :)

Comment: it's better to share your html code , to get exact answers

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#your-select').change(function() {
   location.href = 'newURL';
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<select name="menu" onChange="window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" value="Choose">

        <option value="http://www.url.com">Option 1</option>
        <option value="http://www.url.com">Option 2</option>

 </select>
```